# How do you add custom properties to ios Push Notification payload with javapns?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I'm using javaPNS. The API provides simple to use payload methods to construct various standard payloads. But I also want to send some custom values in the [payload](http://javapns.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/javadoc/index.html) that will serve as additional parameters for the app, (it is [permissible](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)). Looking at the payload object, this doesn't seem possible.

There is nothing that stands out in the "PushNotificationManager" either. So has anyone manage to use JavaPNS and included custom properties in the payload ?

Comment: There is a method `payload` in `Push.class` which allows you to send custom payload (means building the JSON yourself), but there isn't any other way to do that. This is why I prefer https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns since it has a much nicer more OO interface and it supports such stuff per default.

Comment: @miho. Refer to the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one of the `addCustomDictionary` methods for adding custom properties, after using the `complex()` factory method to get an instance of the payload.

```
PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationPayload.complex();
payload.addCustomDictionary ("stringParamKey", "stringValue");
payload.addCustomDictionary ("integerParamKey", 6);
payload.addCustomDictionary ("listParamKey", listOfValues);
```

Comment: Would this be a hybrid use of the dictionary elements ? Dictionary is used for localisation strings and is inside the the "aps" element.

Comment: @giulio These metods are required for adding costom properties (outside of the aps dictionary). All the other methods for adding payload parameters add them inside the aps dictionary.

Comment: Ok. Let me try this and I'll let you know. Thanks. .